# How to use find method to search for an object in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am stuck to find the user by id using the find function. My this `getUsers()` function returns an array of objects.

```
function getUsers(filter, limit, offset) {
  let userList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let user = {};
    user.id = i;
    user.firstname = 'firstname_' + i;
    user.lastname = 'lastname' + i;
    user.email = user.userId + "@hotmail.com";
    userList.push(user);
  }
  return JSON.stringify(userList);
}
```

and I want to find a user by its id here but it shows Data not found:

```
app.get('/shops/:shopid/users/:userId', (req, res) => {
   let users = getUsers(undefined, undefined, undefined);
   const result = users.find(u => u.id === parseInt(req.params.userId));  
   if(!result) res.status(404).send('Data not found');
   res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: Read more about how to use it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Did you try to log req.params.userId to see what it returns? What about the syntax req.params['userId'] as described here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-req-params-property/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `getUsers` returns a JSON string instead of an array. The `find` method only works on arrays. So you have a few options.

Option 1: Simply return the array in `getUSers` function

```
function getUsers(filter, limit, offset) {
  let userList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let user = {};
    user.id = i;
    user.firstname = 'firstname_' + i;
    user.lastname = 'lastname' + i;
    user.email = user.userId + "@hotmail.com";
    userList.push(user);
  }
  return userList;
}
```

Option 2: Use `JSON.parse` when calling `getUsers`

```
app.get('/shops/:shopid/users/:userId', (req, res) => {
   let users = JSON.parse(getUsers(undefined, undefined, undefined));
   const result = users.find(u => u.id === parseInt(req.params.userId));  
   if(!result) res.status(404).send('Data not found');
   res.send(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Your issue

`getUsers()` is returning a `string` but you want to have an array of users, not a string, because a `string` does not have a method `find()`.

Just remove `JSON.stringify()` in you method `getUsers()` and it will work.

```js
function getUsers(filter, limit, offset) {
  let userList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let user = {};
    user.id = i;
    user.firstname = "firstname_" + i;
    user.lastname = "lastname" + i;
    user.email = user.userId + "@hotmail.com";
    userList.push(user);
  }
  // remove a list instead of a string
  return userList;
}

let users = getUsers();
console.log(users);
const result = users.find((u) => u.id === 0);
if (!result) console.log(`User ${result.id} was not found!`);
else console.log(`User ${result.id} was found!`);
```

#### Some remarks

There is no point explicitly calling a function with all parameters as `undefined` as they will automatically be `undefined` if you don't provide them, so `getUsers()` is sufficient.

Your method `getUsers()` can be made more concise and readable by using the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
function getUsers(filter, limit, offset) {
  return [...new Array(100)].map((_, index) => ({
    id: index,
    firstname: `firstname_${index}`,
    lastname: `lastname_${index}`,
    email: `${index}@hotmail.com`,
  }))
}

let users = getUsers();
console.log(users);
const result = users.find((u) => u.id === 0);
if (!result) console.log(`User ${result.id} was not found!`);
else console.log(`User ${result.id} was found!`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```